# How to query pandas data frame where field having dot in field name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

record = {'a': {'b': 1, 'c': 2}}
df = json_normalize(record)
print(df.query("a.b == 1"))
```

Printing below error:
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\scope.py", line 194, in resolve 
    raise compu.ops.UndefinedVariableError(key, is_local) 
pandas.core.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: use a backtick : ```df.query("`a.b`==1")```

Comment: @sammywemmy: I tried that. but getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: and getting `pandas.core.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError: name 'a_' is not defined` error (pandas==0.25.3)

Comment: working fine in pandas==1.0.3